# Folder Action for Ubuntu

Tags: directory, cron, inotify

I have a question concerning Ubuntu folder action ,

I need a script to notify me when a file is add to a folder or the folder changes ,

is there any possibility for that.

I found some articles about **cron** and **inotify** but it was complicated .. i need an easy

method can any on help me .